# dynamicly create and submit form not working in mozila

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
var form = jQuery('<form>', {
'action': $('body').attr('urls') + 'notification/testsponsore',
'target': '_blank',
'mothod': 'POST'
})
form.append($('<input>', {
'name': 'tagViewName',
'value': 'test_tagViewName',
'type': 'hidden'
}));
form.submit();
```

is working fine in chrome but not working in mozilla

Comment: What is the error message you get in Firfox?

Comment: Load of media resource  failed.

Comment: without seeing the context of how you are running this script, my guess is, you're running it inline, and so the $('body') fails, as there is no body element, yet

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
var formElement = document.createElement("form");
formElement.action = $('body').attr('urls') + 'notification/testsponsore';
formElement.target = '_blank';
formElement.method = 'POST';

var element = document.createElement('input');
element.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
element.setAttribute('name', 'tagViewName');
element.setAttribute('value','test_tagViewName');
formElement.appendChild(element);
document.body.appendChild(formElement);
formElement.submit();
```

Comment: it give me error like "TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node."

Comment: You can try proving this :